# specified layout is not rendered for a controller if its action is called from other controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails app, I have a controller "home" and other one "admin". From the index action of home controller am trying to render index action of controller. In the admin controller I have specified the layout to be used i.e. "user_layout" and the home controller is using default application layout.
Following is the home controller

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if user_signed_in?

        @user = User.where(id: current_user.id)
      @user.each do |user|
        @allowed_user = user.allow
      end

        @org = Organization.where(user_id: current_user.id)
        #render :template => 'organizations/show'
      @org.each do |org|
        session[:current_organization_id] = org.id
      end
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { render 'admin/index' }
            format.json { render json:@org}
        end 
    end
  end
end
```

admin controller

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController

    before_filter :authenticate_user!
    layout "user_layout"
  def index
    @org = Organization.where(user_id: current_user.id)
    @user = User.where(id: current_user.id)
      @user.each do |user|
        @allowed_user = user.allow
      end
  end
end
```

However, if the the index action of admin controller is called after visiting some other action of some other controller, than the user_layout is applied but not when it is called from home controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendering the views donot go to the controller, so it does not go to the admin controller and check which layout it should render. you have to specify it in home controller.

Please try this.

```
  format.html { render "admin/index", layout: "user_layout"  }
```

in your respond to block for index action, home controller.